# select use index primary multiples tables

Tags: mysql, primary-key, distinct

I have two tables:

The first table is `item` with id column and the second table is `item_description` with title column
I wish to get distinct rows from the item table and the title from the `item_description table`

I did that :

```
SELECT  distinct id, item_description.title
FROM (item use index (PRIMARY))
```

What is the best request ?

Regards
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can understand, you want to join the two tables. This is done like this:

```
SELECT distinct it.id, idesc.title
FROM item it
JOIN item_description idesc ON it.id=idesc.item_id;
```

Of course, you need a column in your `item_description` table that corresponds to your `id` column in the `item` table.

Comment: Thank you Simon, i know how to join the tables but i wanted this using primary index, because there is many other tables to join

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do. A primary key is a property of a table and often refers to a single attribute (for example an ID). So when you join two tables using the above syntax and one of your join attributes happens to be part of a primary key, Oracle will **automatically** use your index. You do not need to specify this. Or do you mean the SQL "USING" clause that you can use in a JOIN? Here is an example (not Oracle Database, but you'll get the idea): http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqljusing.html